# How do you set the file extension while uploading images through file_save_data?

Tags: files, 9

I am trying to create a product with a product image on drupal using API. I have created a custom module for the same under which following code to upload my image to the Drupal:

```
$path = base64_decode($encodedData['content']);
$data= $this->grabImage($path);
$file = file_save_data($data, null, FileSystemInterface::EXISTS_REPLACE);
        
$id = $file->id();
```

I am using file_save_data drupal method to upload the image successfully and it gets uploaded to the following drupal directory:

> mystore2/web/sites/default/files

Now, I am using this **$file->id() //say 53** value in my product array to connect this image to my product.

```
$image['field_picture'] = [[
    "target_id" => 53,
    "alt" => 'abcd',
    "width"=> 224,
    "height"=> 225,
    "title" => '',
    "target_type" => "file"
]];
```

Follow response I am receiving from API:

```
> message:
>     Unprocessable Entity: validation failed.
>     field_picture.0: Only files with the following extensions are allowed: png gif jpg jpeg.\n
```

So, How can I pass extension in **file_save_data()**? Or how can I add this image to my product?

I am using Drupal version ^9.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the file path, including its name and extension, as the `$destination` parameter:

```
$file = file_save_data($data, 'public://path/to/file.ext', FileSystemInterface::EXISTS_REPLACE);
```

Comment: Where `path/to/file.ext` is whatever you'd like it to be (though you definitely want to be mindful if you're using the `FileSystemInterface::EXISTS_REPLACE` option).